Image in Quarto website hosted on Github Pages not rendering in Firefox
I have created a portfolio website for my projects with Quarto and am hosting it with Github pages.
In Safari all images are rendered and displayed correctly, but not in Firefox. When I try to open the failed image in a new tab it says The image "website-url-to-my-portfolio/image/profile.jpg" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
This is happening in both the index.qmd and about.qmd files using the following code respectively:
---
image: image/profile.jpg
about:
  id: my-info
  template: jolla
  image-shape: round
---

 ---
title: "About Me"
about:
  id: about-info
  template: trestles
  image: image/profile.jpg
  image-shape: rounded
---

Again, this is not an issue I'm seeing in Safari, only Firefox.
This is my first time making a website with quarto and hosting with github pages so any advice or tips would be a huge help!
